# eXistDB no httpclient in version 5.2.0?

Tags: java, namespaces, httpclient, exist-db

I have a question concerning the eXistDB: 
After an upgrade to eXistDB 5.2.0 I get the following error:

*HTTP ERROR 500 javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: An error occurred while processing request to /exist/apps/ediarum/: err:XPST0081 error found while loading module config: Error while loading module modules/config.xqm: error found while loading module ediarum: Error while loading module ./ediarum.xql: Invalid qname httpclient:put. No namespace defined for prefix httpclient. QName is invalid: INVALID_PREFIX*

in Version eXistDB 4.4, everything is working fine...
What exactly is different between 4.4 and 5.2.0 concerning the "httpclient"?

Answer (score 5):

As per the [release notes](http://www.exist-db.org/exist/apps/wiki/blogs/eXist/eXistdb500) for `5.0.0`:

> removed eXist-db's HTTP Client module. Use the EXPath HTTP Client
>   module instead.